# Compare if two strings are equal

Tags: c#, string, list

I want to add inside an `ArrayList` a "clean text" without prepositions and some type of words.

I've got all the banned words inside `Ph` that have a `string` that is separated with "word1,word2,etc...", `textEnArray` is a normal file with a paragraph of a book.

I am trying to check if the value of the banned word isn't the same value of `textEnArray`. If it doesn't correspond I add the value inside an `ArrayList` called `totEnArray`.

I am having trouble because the foreach doesn't compare well if the two values are the same value and it doesn't filter anything and adds all the text inside `ArrayList`.

```
public static ArrayList topFive(string nomFitxer){
    ArrayList totEnArray = new ArrayList();

    string totElText = File.ReadAllText(nomFitxer); 
    string PH = File.ReadAllText(GetValues.obtenirRutaFitxerBlackList());
    char[] delimiterCharsText = { ' ',',', '.', ':', '\t' };
    string[] arrayPH = PH to.Split(',');
    string[] textEnArray = totElText.Split(delimiterCharsText);

    foreach (string paraulaProhibida in arrayPH){

        foreach (string text in textEnArray){
            if (!(paraulaProhibida.Contains(text))){
                totEnArray.Add(text);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, I think you should change `paraulaProhibida.Contains(text)` into `text.Contains(paraulaProhibida)`

Comment: @BojanB - I think the OP should be using `!arrayPH.Contains(text)`. The entire `foreach (string paraulaProhibida in arrayPH)` should be omitted.

Comment: @Enigmativity `arrayPH` are the prohibited words, with the example from the OP this should be single words - while the `text` in `textEnArray` could be sentences or at least parts of sentances - why search for a sentence in a word? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Enigmativity I missed the `space` as a text delimiter, which would split the text into words, sry :) . In this case you are right, omitting the first `foreach` and checking in the array should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am specifically not giving you a full answer, but just wanting to show you what your code could look like. Try this:

```
public static List<string> topFive()
{
    string totElText = "this is, or is not, the source text and should, mostly, be ok";
    string PH = "the,is,not";
    char[] delimiterCharsText = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
    string[] arrayPH = PH.Split(',');
    string[] textEnArray = totElText.Split(delimiterCharsText, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return new List<string>(textEnArray.Where(text => !arrayPH.Contains(text)));
}
```

In this case it gives:

```
this 
or 
source 
text 
and 
should 
mostly 
be 
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Enigmativity pointed out in the comments, you should omit the first `foreach` and search for the word in the whole array. Like this:

```
public static ArrayList topFive(string nomFitxer){
    ArrayList totEnArray = new ArrayList();

    string totElText = File.ReadAllText(nomFitxer); 
    string PH = File.ReadAllText(GetValues.obtenirRutaFitxerBlackList());
    char[] delimiterCharsText = { ' ',',', '.', ':', '\t' };
    string[] arrayPH = PH to.Split(',');
    string[] textEnArray = totElText.Split(delimiterCharsText);

    foreach (string text in textEnArray){
       if (!(arrayPH.Contains(text))){
            totEnArray.Add(text);
       }   
    }
}
```

You can also ad `&& !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)` into the if statement so that empty strings will not be added to the result array.

The reason why you always had all the text in result array was, because you did filter a certain word on the first iteration of your outer `foreach` loop, but not on the second, third,... thus the banned words were still added afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I uderstand you, you want to

- Load black list (or stop words) collection `paraulaProhibida`
- Filter out these words from `nomFitxer` file

You can implement something like this:

```
   string blackListFileName = GetValues.obtenirRutaFitxerBlackList();

   // Hash set is more efficien O(1) than obsolete ArrayList O(N)
   HashSet<String> paraulaProhibida = new HashSet<string>(File
     .ReadLines(blackListFileName)
     .SelectMany(line => new char[] { ',', ';' },  StringSplitOptions.None))
     ,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The main difficulty is to extract a word. In *natural* languages (English, Spanish etc.) a word can well be a very complex notion:

```
   I cannot          // 2 words (shall we split "cannot" into "can" and "not"?)
   I may not         // 3 words 
   Forget-me-not     // 1 word
   Do not forget me  // 4 words
   It's an IT; it is // "It" and "it" are the same, IT is a different (acronym)
   per cent          // do we have 1 word? 2 words?
   George W. Bush    // is "W" a word?
```

That's why for extracting words I suggest using *regular expression*; a simple one as a first try:

```
 "[\p{L}'\-]+"
```

enumerate all words that are not in `paraulaProhibida` and materialize them into an array:

```
   string pattern = @"[\p{L}'\-]+";

   string[] textEnArray = File
     .ReadLines(nomFitxer)
     .SelectMany(line => Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
       .OfType<Match>()
       .Select(match => match.Value))
     .Where(word => !paraulaProhibida.Contains(word))
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether each phrase in textEnArray contains a prohibited word and eliminate them, you can use something like this in place of your loops:

```
totEnArray = new ArrayList(textEnArray.Where(x => !arrayPH.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList());
```

This may solve your problem without changing your code too much, but your code can be improved... For example, you can use an array or List instead of ArrayList...